# Error: global name 'odd' is not defined when creating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a function that returns a dictionary with keys "even" and "odd" and an array of the even & odd values from a range. Here's my codes:

```
    def dictionary_even_odd(x, y):
        d = {}
        for i in range(x, y+1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                d[even].append(i)
            else:
                d[odd].append(i)
        return d
```

However, I get an error message "NameError: global name 'odd' is not defined".

Can anyone points out how to fix these codes? I would really appreciate it!!

**Edit**:

Thanks everyone for the suggestions! It worked after I defined the key names at the beginning.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: And where is `odd` defined?

Comment: Maybe you meant for `d = {}` to be `d = {"even": [], "odd": []}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use defaultdict from collections, and need key of string 'even' and 'odd'

```
import collections 
def dictionary_even_odd(x, y):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(x, y+1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            d['even'].append(i)
        else:
            d['odd'].append(i)
    return d
```

Comment: best thanks is to accept and/or upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your setting to an empty dictionary, but you then try to access keys called `even` and `odd`? You need to *create* the keys `even` and `odd` if you want to use them. Set the keys `even` and `odd` equal to empty lists.

```
def dictionary_even_odd(x, y):
    d = {"even": [], "odd": []}
    for i in range(x, y+1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            d["even"].append(i)
        else:
            d["odd"].append(i)
    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
d = {}
d[foo] = 'bar'
```

Python considers that foo is a variable.
For example,

```
>>> d = {}
>>> foo = 42
>>> d[foo] = 'bar'
>>> d
{42: 'bar'}
```

If you want to have `{'foo': 'bar'}`, you should write

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> d
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dictionary_even_odd(x, y):
d = {'even':[], 'odd':[]}
for i in range(x, y + 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        d['even'].append(i)
    else:
        d['odd'].append(i)
return d
```

This code will work with out importing 'collections'